# How can I resize an image but keep the aspect in HTML?

Tags: html, css

When I use this it fill the box and looses the ratio:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0">
```

When I use this an image can by too tall:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="120" border="0">
```

When I use this an image can by too wide:

```
<img src="test.jpg" height="120" border="0">
```

Is there a way to get the size of an image into a 120x120 size while still keeping the aspect without stretching on either the width or the height?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to mantain the aspect ratio except if you crop the image or resize it to a resolution with the same aspect.

You can use php's GD library to work on the image and try to modify it to your taste. Search over the web for examples of how to do it, and how to use the GD library.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way? Correct me if I am wrong...

```
<img style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px;" src="test.jpg" border="0">
```

Comment: This would work too, from your original email it's unclear if you are trying to scale the image into this area, or make it fill this area... That said, both answers are correct.

Comment: Very nice approach. I wrote a few quick tests: http://jsfiddle.net/xEM88/ -- seems to go fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS with the height set to auto:

```
<img src="test.jpg" style="width:120px; height: auto;" />
```

This way it will fit within a 120px X 120px box, however it won't fill the space as such, but it will fit within it.

Answer (score 0):

For image resizing have a look at these:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

This should point you to what you want to achieve.